# Propagating changes instantly to clients in Azure Virtual Desktop

Tags: azure

we have a Azure Virtual Desktop setup when there is large number of users. Hundreds or even thousands. Each of these users have his own profile stored using FSLogix.

What I'm trying to achive is to change a shortcut to the application that those users has access to via AVD.

Is there any way, possible scalable, way of changing value of that shortcut to be propagated of all the users instantly? Via Group policy objects or any other way.

Thanks in advance